# SQlite NOT throwing exceptions for unknown columns in where clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sqlite

A little background: I am building an App on Laravel 5.6.33 (PHP 7.2 with sqlite 3).

So i have this weird case where in a test I am expecting an Exception but it never gets thrown. So I went digging and found that Laravel does not throw exceptions for invalid/non existent columns in where clause if the database driver is sqlite. The following code just returns an empty collection instead of throwing an exception.

```
\App\Tag::where('notAColumn', 'foo')->get();
```

Its weird and I checked all over the place to see if it was something wrong with my config and found nothing out of place. Debug is set to true etc. Im running this code for testing the app using an in memory sqlite database.

One other thing I noticed was that if I use `whereRaw` instead of `where`, exceptions are thrown as expected. so for example the following throws an exception.

```
\App\Tag::whereRaw('notAColumn = "foo"')->get();
```

Does anyone know why this maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between your two queries is the (non-)quoting of the column name:

```php
Tag::where('notAColumn', 'foo')->get();
// select * from "tags" where "notAColumn" = 'foo'

Tag::whereRaw("notAColumn = 'foo'")->get(); // Literals are wrapped in single quotes.
// select * from "tags" where notAColumn = 'foo'
```

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string literal instead of an identifier.

So SQLite would interpret `Tag::where('notAColumn', 'notAColumn')->get();` as a comparison of two (identical) strings and therefore return all rows in the table.

Comment: wow I am finding this so hard to believe. but it looks like you are spot on. I used the eloquent::toSql method to review the query and its exactly this. Is there any solution to this? Im using mariaDB for the actual app. sqlite testing is letting some bugs go undetected. especially after schema changes.

Comment: do you recommend i test using a mysql db? its pretty slow though.

Comment: I don't really see a solution to this. Yes, I would recommend that. Testing your code with a different database can cause all kinds of issues and hide potential bugs. I know a lot of people use SQLite for testing, but it's definitely not ideal. The more complex and database-centric your application gets, the more differences you'll find between these two databases.